# Can't turn off iTunes on MacBookAir

Tags: itunes, mac

I cannot quit from iTunes, possibly because there is a pop-up that will not cancel, despite dozens of times pressing the cancel button.  I turned off the machine and when I turned it back on, there was iTunes and the stubborn pop-up.  I'm using MacBookAir, bought in December 2019.

Comment: have you tried **Cmd+Q** yet?  (quits the current entire app)

Comment: Knowing what the pop-up says would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple things happening here. If you have the spinny wheel, iTunes is obviously hanging/not responding. You can fully quit it by using `Option` + `Command` + `Escape`, selecting iTunes, and pressing `Force Quit`. If that doesn't work, you can open Activity Monitor (You can press `Command` + `Space` and then type `Activity Monitor`), find and select iTunes, and press the Stop symbol with an X in the center, and that should be the end of that. If none of this works, you can restart.